# Grabbing all rows from a database that have specific column values in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am dealing with a table that has a bunch of short names, ex.

| some_id | long_name | short_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 94 | March | mar |
| 19 | April | apr |
| 0 | June | jun |
| 2 | September | Sep |

I want to grab only a few supported short names, ex. mar, sep, jun.

How would I go about doing it in laravel?

Currently I have something like this:
`$this->result = DB::table('table_above')->get();`

But this just grabs every table. I was thinking of adding the where command, but not sure how to check for multiple values.
`$this->result = DB::table('table_above')->where('short_name', [somehow say either mar, sep, jun])->get();`

At the end I'd like an array that holds a dictionary of rows (i.e $result) with the supported short names (i.e here mar, june, sept).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query
DB :: table ('table_above')->whereIn('short_name', ['mar', 'sep'])->get()

Comment: Thank you so much! That snippet worked perfectly!